# Do divs expand vertically to fit their children divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting my divs to vertically expand with their children divs.

I have something like this:

```
<div class='headerWrapper'>
    <div class='header'>
        <img..... height=100>
    </div>
</div>
```

In firebug,  the header div has a height of 100,  the headerWrapper div has a height of 0.

The image is visible in the div beneath it....  There is no fixed height on the headerWrapper div.

So confused.

Thanks-
Jonathan

Comment: Can you post your styles as well? Particularly, is `.header` or its contents floated or absolutely positioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check and see if you have the header div set to float.

When a child element floats and its parent does not, this causes the parent element to "collapse" to a height of 0.

This [page](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) seems to have a pretty good description of the problem about halfway down the page.

Comment: I found [Clearing Floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) to be very helpful. I'm not sure though that it really matters whether the parent container floats. Even if the parent container itself floats, wouldn't it still contain its floating children?

Answer (score 3):

If you floats them, you can use a lil css trick to make em high :)

solution 1: auto overflow the parents

```
<style type="text/css">
    .headerWrapper {overflow: auto;}
    .header {overflow: auto;}
</stlye>
<div class='headerWrapper'>
    <div class='header'>
        <img..... height=100>
    </div>
</div>
```

solution 2: use clearfix after em

```
<style type="text/css">
    .clearfix:after {visibility: hidden;display: block;font-size: 0;content: " ";clear: both;height: 0;}
</stlye>
<div class='headerWrapper clearfix'>
    <div class='header clearfix'>
        <img..... height=100>
    </div>
</div>
```